# How can I merge two .g729 files into one .wav file with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I merge two `.g729` files into one `.wav` file with `ffmpeg`?

I used the command

```
ffmpeg -filter_complex [0\:a][1\:a]amerge\=inputs\=2[aout] -map [aout]
```

The result is with two files reported `.wav` and not `.g729` and output reported `.wav`
Here is the FFMPEG data:

```
ffmpeg version git-2015-07-01-06a0d5e Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.3 (SUSE Linux)
configuration: --prefix=/home/cartella/Encoder_Build --extra-cflags=-I/home/cartella/Encoder_Build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/cartella/Encoder_Build/lib --bindir=/home/cartella/Encoder --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --disable-yasm
libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
libavcodec     56. 46.100 / 56. 46.100
libavformat    56. 40.100 / 56. 40.100
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 19.100 /  5. 19.100
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Comment: That's not a complete command: it is missing inputs and output(s). Show the full log from the command.

Comment: Hi ☺️ with this  ffmpeg -filter_complex [0\:a][1\:a]amerge\=inputs\=2[aout] I have this output :  start merge  process...[ /home/cartella/Encoder/ffmpeg -i /home/cartella/files/input1.wav -i /home/cartella/files/input2.wav -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout] -map [aout] /home/cartella/files/output.wav]  my expected result is start merge  process...[ /home/cartella/Encoder/ffmpeg -i /home/cartella/files/input1.g729 -i /home/cartella/files/input2.g729 -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout] -map  [aout] /home/cartella/files/output.wav